# Separating multiple variables using tidyr

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a dataframe `df` with ten variables `var1, var2, var3,...,var10` to be separated. The values of the variables have this form: value_text. I would like to apply `tidyr::separate()` and actually I did ten times, once per variable.

```
tidyr::separate(col=var1,into=c("value1","text1"),extra="merge")%>%
tidyr::separate(col=var2,into=c("value2","text2"),extra="merge")%>%
```

...

Do you know any "more elegant" way to use `tidyr::separate()` at once (without separating 10 times)?

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: If you're OK with not using "tidyr", you can use `cSplit` from "splitstackshape"....

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I would prefer using tidyr

Comment: Then gather, split, gather again, unite, add row indices, and spread the data wide. Or `cSplit(df, names(df), "_")`.....

Comment: Update of my imagination of the solution: I was thinking about something like this but it did not work ("Error: Invalid column specification"): tidyr::separate(paste0("Year_",2005:2015),c(paste0("Value_",‌​2005:2015),paste0("T‌​ext_",2005:2015)),ex‌​tra="merge",convert=‌​TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of at the moment is something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
  gather(var, val, everything()) %>%            # Gather all the columns into a key-value pair 
  separate(val, into = c("value", "text")) %>%  # Separate the gathered columns
  gather(key, val, value, text) %>%             # Gather again so you have key-key-value
  unite(cn, var, key) %>%                       # Unite your keys to become the column names
  group_by(cn) %>%                              # Keys are duplicated; we need to know their origins
  mutate(rn = sequence(n())) %>%                # .. so we add row numbers
  spread(cn, val)                               # Then we convert to the wide form
# # A tibble: 5 × 21
#      rn var1_text var1_value var10_text var10_value var2_text var2_value var3_text var3_value var4_text var4_value
# * <int>     <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>
# 1     1      POIL        235       ZHKV         555      QVWK        479      SKCY        454      YCTY        704
# 2     2      NENB        928       CJLE         956      JXQT        379      HPCV        186      VIQY        764
# 3     3      HFHX        966       PZZE         622      PXHE        261      IUGF        717      YIGE        842
# 4     4      LUWK        021       OJRH         741      XNWE        230      NGEN        486      INYN        003
# 5     5      BISI        637       MEJS         718      TSYO        383      ODGS        755      GBKW        564
# # ... with 10 more variables: var5_text <chr>, var5_value <chr>, var6_text <chr>, var6_value <chr>,
# #   var7_text <chr>, var7_value <chr>, var8_text <chr>, var8_value <chr>, var9_text <chr>, var9_value <chr>
# Warning message:
# attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

Here's the sample data I used:

```
library(stringi)
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(sprintf("%s_%s", stri_rand_strings(50, 3, "[0-9]"), 
                                  stri_rand_strings(50, 4, "[A-Z]")), ncol = 10,
                          dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("var", 1:10))))
mydf
#       var1     var2     var3     var4     var5     var6     var7     var8     var9    var10
# 1 235_POIL 479_QVWK 454_SKCY 704_YCTY 924_JDJQ 883_TYMP 206_BCJE 214_FDZI 944_DFVS 555_ZHKV
# 2 928_NENB 379_JXQT 186_HPCV 764_VIQY 362_KRRO 794_MCGM 877_HEGE 959_NRCD 174_GMCJ 956_CJLE
# 3 966_HFHX 261_PXHE 717_IUGF 842_YIGE 470_LLHP 733_JYNI 448_MUAN 734_BYRC 522_ZQRI 622_PZZE
# 4 021_LUWK 230_XNWE 486_NGEN 003_INYN 838_XDKF 727_HUSE 663_WJBD 107_MMJZ 550_KZWY 741_OJRH
# 5 637_BISI 383_TSYO 755_ODGS 564_GBKW 334_LDLY 121_BTQE 296_IEDF 146_EVBK 069_VUGT 718_MEJS
```

---

> NOTE: This seems to be entirely the opposite data format of what would be recommended by the authors of the "tidyverse" set of packages.

---

As mentioned, an alternative would be to use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package. With that, the problem is easily resolved as follows:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mydf, names(mydf), "_", type.convert = FALSE)
##    var1_1 var1_2 var2_1 var2_2 var3_1 var3_2 var4_1 var4_2 var5_1 var5_2 var6_1 var6_2 var7_1 var7_2 var8_1 var8_2
## 1:    235   POIL    479   QVWK    454   SKCY    704   YCTY    924   JDJQ    883   TYMP    206   BCJE    214   FDZI
## 2:    928   NENB    379   JXQT    186   HPCV    764   VIQY    362   KRRO    794   MCGM    877   HEGE    959   NRCD
## 3:    966   HFHX    261   PXHE    717   IUGF    842   YIGE    470   LLHP    733   JYNI    448   MUAN    734   BYRC
## 4:    021   LUWK    230   XNWE    486   NGEN    003   INYN    838   XDKF    727   HUSE    663   WJBD    107   MMJZ
## 5:    637   BISI    383   TSYO    755   ODGS    564   GBKW    334   LDLY    121   BTQE    296   IEDF    146   EVBK
##    var9_1 var9_2 var10_1 var10_2
## 1:    944   DFVS     555    ZHKV
## 2:    174   GMCJ     956    CJLE
## 3:    522   ZQRI     622    PZZE
## 4:    550   KZWY     741    OJRH
## 5:    069   VUGT     718    MEJS
```

Another option if you want to stick with the tidyverse is to use a `for` loop.

```
for (i in names(mydf)) mydf <- separate_(mydf, i, paste0(i, c("_text", "_value")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do appreciate your effort in this detailed answer. However, I am looking for something easier. The variables names have this form: Year_2005, Year_2006...Year_2010. The new separated variables should have this form: Value_2005, Text_2005, Value_2006, Text_2006...Value_2010, Text_2010. Therefore, I was thinking about something like this but it did not work ("Error: Invalid column specification"): `tidyr::separate(paste0("Year_",2005:2015),c(paste0("Value_",2005:2015),paste0("Text_",2005:2015)),extra="merge",convert=TRUE)`

Comment: @ungatoverde, I hope you saw my note in the middle of my post. What you're doing goes against the tidy data principles, so you are not likely to find a convenient solution using the "tidyverse".

Comment: @ungatoverde, The other option might be to use a `for` loop where you loop across the names and separate them individually.... Shouldn't be too tough to work with.

Comment: @ungatoverde, example: `for (i in names(mydf)) mydf <- separate_(mydf, i, paste0(i, c("_text", "_value")))`.

Comment: Great! I Like this suggestion. If you insert it as answer for my question I will accepted. Thanks.